# GCC v4.6 vs 4.7

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gnu

What's the difference? is one better or are the older versions only kept for the sake of keeping?
I saw that 4.5 is no longer available.
I'm using 4.6.2, and it seems to be fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of the major changes [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html). If you're happy with the version you're currently using, I suppose there's no hurry to upgrade though.

The GCC project generally maintains two stable release branches. Currently those branches are 4.6.x and 4.7.x.